# Pycharm how to show strings in debugger without escapes

Tags: debugging, pycharm

If I have a string  consisting of these characters: I'm rich!  and I look at this string in the pyCharm debugger, I'm shown   `'I\\'m rich!'`

Is it possible to see it without the leading, trailing, and escaped single quotes (ie as it would be stored in memory)?

In more complex strings all the escaping shown by the debugger can make it hard to really understand what characters really are, or are not, in the string.

Michael